# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, before-save, server-side-validation

In my model, I have:

```
validates_presence_of :start_date, :message => 'Please enter date.'
validate :start_date_exist_check , on: :create`

def start_date_exist_check 
  @check_date = Employee.where('start_date = ?', start_date)`
  if @check_date.blank?
  end
end
```

`validate_presence_of` is executed after my module `start_date_exist_check`, which creates a problem.

Can anybody tell me how I can validate the field first?

Comment: you mean to say, first custom validate method is calling and then after `validates_presence_of` . right ?

Comment: does my answer worked ?

Comment: Yes, i accepted it also thanks

Comment: Can you also upvote it ?

Comment: I upvoted it but as I do not have 15 reputations it will not be displayed publicly

Comment: Ohh,, no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check whether the start date is blank or not , if its blank, return it from first line

```
validates_presence_of :start_date, :message => 'Please enter date.'
validate :start_date_exist_check , on: :create`

def start_date_exist_check 
  return if start_date.blank?
  @check_date = Employee.where('start_date = ?', start_date)`
  if @check_date.blank?
  end
end
```

**Not tested**
let me know if its not work